# Simple example of Twitter api request

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth

Could someone just show an example of simple twitter api request?

Apparently, i'm setting wrong headers, but i don't get what exactly is wrong.

URL:

```
'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/followers/ids.json?username=J7mbo'
```

Request headers:

```
{
  'oauth_access_token': '...'
  'oauth_access_token_secret': '...'
  'consumer_key': '...'
  'consumer_secret': '...'
}
```

Please, don't overcomplicate this with language-specific snippets or additional libraries. All i need is working REST api request.
If it's important, i'm using [superagent](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent), which means JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

If you are logged in and have a Application already registered then the form at the bottom of the page will show you an example.

https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/followers/ids

[image: Follower IDs]

Any concrete example with specific headers would leak access to a twitter account and be invalid soon due to time stamps in the signing process.

Comment: Sorry, may be i just don't get something. I use Postman (chrome app) to test requests. I've selected an app in the "Select one of your apps", then i've clicked "Get OAuth signature", and got "OAuth Signing Results". I've used headers from "Authorization header" for my Postman get request. It returns "Bad Authentication data". Could you just post example of all custom headers, that need to be used in this request? Just replace your creds with placeholders